# How to change the default titles in p:galleria for all images to specific titles for each image

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2

I implemented the example in PrimeFaces for the `p:galleria`. I can display my images and such with no problem. But I want each image to have it's own title. Here's my code:

```
<p:galleria value="#{mywork.images}" var="image" panelWidth="500" panelHeight="313"
    showCaption="true" style="left:350px;">
    <p:graphicImage name="/galleria/dotacion/#{image}" alt="Image Description for #{image}"
        title="#{mywork.titles}" style="width:100%;"/>
</p:galleria>
```

and here is my bean:

```
package org.portfolio.util;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;

@ManagedBean
public class Mywork {

    private List<String> images;
    private String titles = "";
    private String titles2 = "";

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        images = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (int i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
            images.add("pierrel"+i+".jpg");
            if (i == 1) {
                titles = "imagen de prueba if1";
                getTitles();
            }
            if (i == 2){
                titles = "imagen de prueba if2";
                getTitles();
            }
        }
    }

    public List<String> getImages() {
        return images;
    }

    public String getTitles() {
        return titles;
    }

    public String getTitles2() {
        return titles2;
    }  
}
```

What I am doing wrong or missing?

This is just returning me "imagen de prueba if2" for every image.

Comment: thx for the edit on the post, my first one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an Object instead of using a list of string.

In you ManagedBean

```
@ManagedBean
public class Mywork {

private List<ImageObject> images;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    images = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (int i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
        images.add(new ImageObject("fileName" + i + ".jpg", "myDescription", "myTitle"));
    }
}

public class ImageObject{
   private String fileName;
   private String description;
   private String title;

  public ImageObject(String fileName, String description, String title){
   this.fileName = fileName;
   this.description = description;
   this.title = title;
  }

  //Getters setters
 }

}
```

in your xhtml

```
<p:galleria value="#{mywork.images}" var="image" panelWidth="500" panelHeight="313" showCaption="true" style="left:350px;">
        <p:graphicImage name="/galleria/dotacion/#{image.fileName}" alt="#{image.description}" title="#{image.title}" style="width:100%;"/>
    </p:galleria>
```